# ASP.NET - Associar controlador a view parcial vazia

Tags: asp.net

Tenho uma Razor view parcial vazia que não depende de nenhuma entidade do meu modelo de classes. Pretendo colocar duas drodpowns com um botão para cada uma que permita adicionar registos. Para isso, vou precisar de um controlador. Como faço para associar um controlador a uma Razor view parcial vazia que não está associada a nenhuma classe?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem o que você quis expressar, a view não precisa ter relação com a controller, apenas ser chamada por ela.. normalmente quando a view possui uma model, você manda "return View(model)" , neste caso seria "return view()"

Comment: Como o @M.Bertolazo comentou, não é preciso associar a view com a controller, e normalmente uma view sem model, que acho que é o que queres dizer com "não depende de nenhuma entidade", geralmente é algo como um meno estático por exemplo, que precisa ser executada por um controller, pode simplesmente estar incluída em outra view

Comment: Já percebi. Obrigado!